# CrudRepository return wrong set of result

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, crud-repository

I have a problem with Hibernate and CrudRepository.

I have a controller that return a set of result taken by a View.
I create a View because i think is the best way to manage my Database Entities, that are created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Characters (
  CHARACTER_ID INT ,
  CHARACTER_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CHARACTER_ICON VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  clevel INT NOT NULL,
  experience INT NOT NULL,
  TOTAL_EXPERIENCE INT NOT NULL,
  health INT NOT NULL,
  HEALTH_STATUS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CHARACTER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE GUILDROLE (
ROLE_ID INT NOT NULL,
GUILD_ID INT NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
SALARY INT NOT NULL,
MANAGER BIT NOT NULL,
ROLE_IMG VARCHAR(250),
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(800),
GUILD_LEVEL INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ROLE_ID,GUILD_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE GUILDMEMBER (
CHARACTER_ID INT NOT NULL,
ROLE_ID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(CHARACTER_ID,ROLE_ID)
);

CREATE VIEW V_GUILDMEMBERS
AS
SELECT
 GR.GUILD_ID AS GUILD_ID,
 GR.ROLE_ID AS ROLE_ID,
 CH.CHARACTER_ID AS CHARACTER_ID,
 CH.CHARACTER_NAME AS CHARACTER_NAME,
 GR.GUILD_LEVEL AS GUILD_LEVEL,
 GR.NAME AS ROLE_NAME,
 GR.ROLE_IMG AS ROLE_IMG
FROM GUILDMEMBER GM
 JOIN GUILDROLE GR
ON GM.ROLE_ID = GR.ROLE_ID
 JOIN CHARACTERS AS CH
ON CH.CHARACTER_ID = GM.CHARACTER_ID;
```

I've implemented the class that model the View like this:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Immutable
@Data
public class V_GuildMembers {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GUILD_ID")
    private Integer guildId;

    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    private Integer roleId;

    @Column(name = "CHARACTER_ID")
    private Integer characterId;

    @Column(name = "CHARACTER_NAME")
    private String characterName;

    @Column(name = "GUILD_LEVEL")
    private Integer guildLevel;

    @Column(name = "ROLE_NAME")
    private String roleName;

    @Column(name = "ROLE_IMG")
    private String roleImg;

}
```

My RepositoryService looks like this:

```
public List<V_GuildMembers> getGuildMembers(Integer guildId){
        List<V_GuildMembers> members = new ArrayList<>();
        if(guildId != null){
            members = guildMemberListRepository.findMembersByGuildId(guildId);
        }
        return members;
    }
```

and last, i have my repository interface like this:

```
import com.novavrbe.vrbe.dto.V_GuildMembers;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface GuildMemberListRepository extends CrudRepository<V_GuildMembers, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<V_GuildMembers> {

    default List<V_GuildMembers> findMembersByGuildId(Integer guildId) {
        return findAll(
                (root, query, criteriaBuilder)-> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("guildId"), guildId)
        );

    }

    default Optional<V_GuildMembers> getGuildMemberbyID(Integer characterid){

        return findOne(((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("characterId"),characterid)));

    }
}
```

Everything works perfect without using CrudRepository and using a normal Select on Sql Manager or MySql Workbench.
I've added 3 guild member in the same Giuld, with different name and role, but the result set that i get from the controller , and from the method findMembersByGuildId(guildId) is the following:

```
"members": [
        {
            "role_ID": 5,
            "character_ID": 1,
            "guild_LEVEL": 50,
            "guild_ID": 1,
            "role_IMG": "",
            "character_NAME": "Marzio Paparzio",
            "role_NAME": "Legatus"
        },
        {
            "role_ID": 5,
            "character_ID": 1,
            "guild_LEVEL": 50,
            "guild_ID": 1,
            "role_IMG": "",
            "character_NAME": "Marzio Paparzio",
            "role_NAME": "Legatus"
        },
        {
            "role_ID": 5,
            "character_ID": 1,
            "guild_LEVEL": 50,
            "guild_ID": 1,
            "role_IMG": "",
            "character_NAME": "Marzio Paparzio",
            "role_NAME": "Legatus"
        }
    ]
```

In fact it seems like the result replicate one of the record the exact number of time of the result.
I hope someone can give me an help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because the `@Id` is on the `guildId` which is the same for each and thus hibernate sees it as the same entity and will return it for the rows. Basically it is your mapping that is wrong. What happens is the first row gets mapped, then hibernate will for the next row see if an entity with that primary key already exists in the session and it does because it just mapped the first row (and `@Id` is mapped to `guildId` and as the primary-key is the same for hibernate it is the same entity and it will look no further).

Comment: Ok, understand the problem. What do you suggest to overcome this problem? How can i map my attribute in order to make Hibernate works? do i need to change my database structure?

Comment: You need to change your entity to use a composed primary key. Glancing over your code the PK of `V_GuildMembers` should be the combination of `guildId`, `roleId` and `characterId`. Put `@Id` an all of them.

Comment: Ok, i Solved the problem modifing the @Id annotation, placing it on the characher_id attribute instead of guild_id.

Comment: That will work for this case, but if the same character is in multiple guilds you still have the same issue. So it really needs to be a composite key on multiple fields for everything to work.